# Is **on to** a conventional contraction of "let's back on to" when presenting a lecture?

Tags: meaning

It sounds like the video is [saying](https://youtu.be/ok_r-mody8w?t=59) (link with a time stamp corresponds the following)

> All right, **on to** today's show, which is ...

I guess this is an expression to drag the attention of audience back on to a topic.

the question is,

Is **on to** a conventional contraction of "let's back on to" when presenting a lecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. "Let's back on to" is not idiomatic.

"On to [something]" is a short form of "[moving on [to something]](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Moving+On)" which indicates a change to a different subject or activity.

In the video, the speaker finishes promoting her website, and then indicates a subject change by saying "on to today's show..."